# Jenkins Pipeline Ansible is stuck on SSH connection

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have a job in my Jenkins pipeline which deploys the application on the infrastructure created by terraform. Terraform creates infrastructure and appends IP addresses inside `aws_hosts` file.

I am stuck on ansible stage with below output in Jenkins -

```
[terransible_jenkins-setup@2] $ ansible-playbook playbooks/main.yml -i terraform/aws_hosts 
--private-key /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terransible_jenkins-setup@2/ssh6611349626016340230.key 
-u jenkins -vvv

ansible-playbook [core 2.14.6]

  config file = None

  configured module search path = ['/var/jenkins_home/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']

  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ansible

  ansible collection location = /var/jenkins_home/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections

  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook

  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] (/usr/bin/python3)

  jinja version = 3.1.2

  libyaml = True

No config file found; using defaults

host_list declined parsing /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terransible_jenkins-setup@2/terraform/aws_hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method

auto declined parsing /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terransible_jenkins-setup@2/terraform/aws_hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method

Parsed /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terransible_jenkins-setup@2/terraform/aws_hosts inventory source with ini plugin

Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.

Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.

Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.



PLAYBOOK: main.yml *************************************************************

1 plays in playbooks/main.yml



PLAY [Install Docker] **********************************************************



TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************

task path: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terransible_jenkins-setup@2/playbooks/main.yml:2

<13.235.246.69> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu

<13.235.246.69> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto 
-o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/var/jenkins_home/workspace/terransible_jenkins-setup@2/ssh6611349626016340230.key"' 
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey 
-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ubuntu"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 
-o 'ControlPath="/var/jenkins_home/.ansible/cp/4442d69233"' 13.235.246.69 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ubuntu && sleep 0'"'"''
```

I've tried to executing ansible playbooks locally without Jenkins at that time it works fine...
This tells me that there is no problem with the ec2 instances...